# Value not inserting into sqlite from my application

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

```
NSString *query = @"INSERT INTO PatientInfo (PatientName,PatientId,PatientMobile,PatientEmail,Patientdates,Patientdesc) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_sqldatabase, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"In Insert function");
    char* errmsg;

    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [userModel.PatientName UTF8String] ,-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [userModel.PatientId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [userModel.MobileNo UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [userModel.PEmail UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [userModel.date UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [userModel.description UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE )
    {
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_exec(_sqldatabase, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
        NSLog( @"addUser Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_sqldatabase) );
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_exec(_sqldatabase, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
        NSLog(@"Data Inserted into Table.PatientInfo");
        return YES;
    }
}
```

I am using the above code for inserting values into database but it is not inserting value why?

Comment: what is error Message

Comment: What is the schema definition for that table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE "PatientInfo" ("P_Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "PatientName" VARCHAR, "PatientId" VARCHAR, "PatientMobile" VARCHAR, "PatientEmail" VARCHAR, "Patientdates" VARCHAR, "Patientdesc" TEXT)

Comment: Why aren't you logging the `sqlite3_errmsg` if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails?

Comment: Why do you call `COMMIT` if `sqlite3_step` fails?

Comment: The logging is also broken on the `sqlite_step()` failure anyway as you perform other actions before reporting an error.

Comment: this is the error message Printing description of errmsg:
(char *) errmsg = 0x00000001001352eb "insertPatientInfo:"
Printing description of *(errmsg):
(char) *errmsg = 'i'

Comment: That makes no sense and it isn't coming from the code you posted.

Comment: 'Error when counting rows  attempt to write a readonly database' 
this is the exact error message i got

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

1. Where you calling `sqlite3_errmsg`, you are performing other SQLite calls in between the occurrence of the error and the subsequent call to `sqlite3_errmsg`. This can result in the error message being lost. Make sure to call `sqlite3_errmsg` immediately after identifying a problem.
2. If `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, you don't appear to have an `else` clause. Make sure to examine `sqlite3_errmsg` if the prepare fails.
3. Having tackled the above, you mention that it says that the database is readonly. Are you opening the database from the app bundle? The bundle is not writable, which might result in this error.

   If the database is included in the app bundle, the typical workflow is

   - see if the database has been copied to the Documents folder;
   - if not, copy the database from the bundle to the Documents folder;
   - now open the database in the Documents folder rather than the bundle.
4. Unrelated to your question at hand, you only need to perform `COMMIT` if you started a transaction (e.g. `BEGIN TRANSACTION`). If not, no `COMMIT` is needed.

   You certainly don't need to commit the changes if the `INSERT` failed.